# How to convert duplicated data to transposed data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

I create a dataset with 2 columns,
there are names in column 1 and name data is duplicate itself.
Column 2 contain different scores of names.
I want to convert data like screenshoot. Is there any way to do it?
[image: Excel]

I tried creating a pivot table from transposed data but it’s not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps try something along the lines:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `A13`

```
=LET(array,A2:A11,
Col,COUNTIF(A2:A11,A2:A11),
VSTACK(HSTACK($A$1,$B$1&SEQUENCE(,MAX(Col))),
IFERROR(UNIQUE(HSTACK(A2:A11,MAKEARRAY(ROWS(array),MAX(Col),
LAMBDA(r,c,INDEX(FILTER(B2:B11,array=INDEX(array,r)),c))))),"Nan")))
```

---

The above task can also be performed quite elegantly using **Power Query**

[image]

---

Follow the steps to use **Power Query**:

• First convert the source range into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as `Table1`

---

• Next, open a blank query from `Data` Tab --> `Get & Transform Data` --> `Get Data` --> `From Other Sources` --> `Blank Query`

---

• The above lets the `Power Query` window opens, now from `Home Tab` --> `Advanced Editor` --> And paste the following by removing whatever you see, and press `Done`

---

**M-Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table9"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Name", type text}, {"Score", type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Name"}, {{"Score", each Text.Combine([Score],","), type nullable text}}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Score", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Score.1", "Score.2", "Score.3", "Score.4", "Score.5"}),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Split Column by Delimiter",null,"Nan",Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Score.1", "Score.2", "Score.3", "Score.4", "Score.5"})
in
    #"Replaced Value"
```

---

[image]

---

• Lastly, to import it back to `Excel` --> Click on `Close & Load` or `Close & Load To` --> The first one which clicked shall create a new sheet with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.

---