# Transposing a row to multiple columns based on ID in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I need to transpose multiple row data (in a single column) to multiple columns (on a single row) for each unique ID. In the full data set there are 350+ IDs with numerous violations (can be in the hundreds) listed for each. The specific number of violations vary by ID and need to be maintained in order. The manipulated dataset can be on the same excel sheet or a new one.

I have tried formula coding within the datasheet, but to no avaiable. I believe this would be best handled by VBA, but am willing to use point of click/ formula options.

[image: From this]

[image: To this]

Thank you.

Comment: Afaik Solution using `Power Query` will be more easy & using `Excel Formulas` shown as well [How to convert duplicated data to transposed data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76533697/how-to-convert-duplicated-data-to-transposed-data)

Comment: Please take some time to research the community, have been solved quite a multiple times. Here is another one : **[Look Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76468190/how-can-i-return-unique-values-horizontally-based-off-another-list-on-excel)** & **[One_More](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76227653/based-on-the-2-column-data-need-to-look-up-and-data-to-another-sheet-horizontal)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this can be done with two formulas, one for the ID column and one for the violation columns:

For the ID column, use `=UNIQUE($A$2:$A$9)`

For the remaining, use `=TOROW(IF(E2=$A$2:$A$9,$B$2:$B$9,NA()),2)`, this formula needs to be copied down.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```vb
Sub macro1()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, r As Long, lastrow As Long
    Dim col As Collection, i As Long, n As Long, t0 As Single
    t0 = Timer
    
    Set col = New Collection
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ws
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        ' scan up sheet
        For r = lastrow To 2 Step -1
            ' look above
            If .Cells(r, "A") = Cells(r - 1, "A") Then
                col.Add .Cells(r, "B").Value2, CStr(r) ' add to collection
                '.Rows(r).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 100, 100)
                .Rows(r).EntireRow.Delete
                n = n + 1
            Else
                For i = 1 To col.Count
                   .Cells(r, col.Count - i + 3) = col(i)
                Next
                Set col = New Collection
            End If
        Next
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox n & " lines merged", vbInformation, _
           Format(Timer - t0, "0.0 secs")

End Sub
```